# CSS animation flickers on transform: translate3d along with width

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a tab based component, in which the active tab has an underline which animate between tabs. The underline is a seperate div whose width and position will be calculated dynamically . Instead of position absolute I am using translate3d.

```
.active-bar {
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

This bar has the below animation calculated dynamically.

```
transform: translate3d(463.484px, 0px, 0px);
width: 32px;
```

to

```
transform: translate3d(20px, 0px, 0px);
width: 254px;
```

But there is a flicker which I see at times but not always. What is the solution I need to use to avoid the flicker.

Comment: Those _not always_ issues is often computer related, like the graphic cards (or processor) were busy and got a hick up ... have you tried on another device, maybe with more _horse power_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the transition smoother (and less CPU dependent) , use only a transform, and a fixed width. Change this dynamic style :

```
transform: translate3d(463.484px, 0px, 0px);
width: 32px;
```

to

```
width: 100px;   /* fixed in the element */
```

and the dynamic part (that will get a width of 32px)

```
transform: translate3d(463.484px, 0px, 0px) scaleX(0.32);
```

Comment: I just saw it were an _underline_ animation, not text, so scale will be perfectly fine :) ...+1

Comment: Btw, since only moving along x-axis, have you ever tested if the none 3d `translate` perform better?

Comment: @LGSon Usually, a 3D transform would use GPU, and usually a 2D transform would use CPU, so probably the 3D is better. But it would be better to test the specific case, anyway.